# Can we use msmq messaging with wcf data service

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, wcf-data-services

I have a Wcf Data service exposing entities from Ado.net entity framework. I would like to know whethere I can use msmq messaging with my data service.
After searching on internet i could find links for using with a wcf service only.
Please provide some links with a sample.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

WCF Data Services is using HTTP/REST **only** - it cannot be used over any other protocol or with any other binding.

MSMQ is only available when you use "regular" WCF services that use the SOAP protocol for communication - that can be routed over different transport media.

REST is very tightly and intimately tied to HTTP only.

Answer (score 0):

WCF supports MSMQ as a transport protocol and provides the standard MSMQ binding.  Here is a link to MSDN article devoted to using MSMQ in a WCF application:

[How to: Exchange Messages with WCF Endpoints and Message Queuing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)

Comment: This is with respect to a wcf service, but i am looking for wcf data service