# WCF Data Services and MSMQ

Tags: msmq, wcf-data-services

I've got a database which contains an Order table. I'm trying to create an API for our clients so they can manipulate the data within the Order table. I have chosen to go down the route of a WCF Data Service so that clients can perform CRUD operation via URI's.

However I need to ensure this WCF Data Service is scalable and can handle a large number of requests(1000) made from multiple clients. I've looked at using MSMQ with WCF Data services but looking at the following link this seems impossible -
[Can we use msmq messaging with wcf data service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754502/can-we-use-msmq-messaging-with-wcf-data-service).

My work around is when a client attempts to manipulate the data (not selects), instead of waiting for the changes to be saved to the db we add the request to a MSMQ. This is done by overriding the SaveChanges() method in the ORM and extracting the changes, serialise them into the MSMQ and then return to the client. A separate thread will then pull objects from the MSMQ and then save the changes to the db.

This all seem fine but how do I notify the client that its request has been processed or errored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any offline processing of a usually synchronous operation will incur this problem.

It is one of the problems faced when implementing CQRS pattern, which attempts to decouple reads and write operations. This has been termed *eventual consistency*.

There are actually many different techniques for addressing this problem - have a look at these links:

[CQRS - Eventual Consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414277/cqrs-eventual-consistency)

[GUI recommandations for eventual consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316487/gui-recommandations-for-eventual-consistency)